# Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability

Given $n$ mutually independent Bernoulli trials each with success probability of $1/n^2$, what is the expected number of successes?

I think it should be $n/n^2$, but not sure.  Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: you are right :) expected value of a Binomial distribution is n*p where n is the number of trials and p the probability of success. and n Bernoulli trials for a Binomial distribution

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  Here's a derivation of the result.

Let $X$ be the random variable that takes only values $0$ or $1$ and
$$
P(X = 1) = \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$

The variable that counts the total number of successes in $n$ trials is the sum
$$
Y = X_1 + \cdots + X_n,
$$
where each $X_i = X$.  Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
E(Y) &= E(X_1 + \cdots + X_n) \\
&= E(X_1) + \cdots + E(X_n) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n^2} \\
&= \frac{n}{n^2}.
\end{align}
$$